# How to debug "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"?

Tags: mysql

I ran into this problem when child row cannot be updated.

Below is the code that I worked with: two tables were created `PUBLISHER` and `BOOK`, then some information was added to the `PUBLISHER` table while `BOOK` table was empty, then when I try to add information to the `BOOK` table it gives me an error.

This is created PUBLISHER table:

```
MySQL [rdatabase]> `CREATE TABLE PUBLISHER (PUBLISHER_CODE CHAR (3) PRIMARY KEY, PUBLISHER_NAME CHAR (25), CITY CHAR (20));`

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
```

This is created BOOK table:

```
MySQL [rdatabase]> `CREATE TABLE BOOK (BOOK_CODE CHAR (4) PRIMARY KEY, TITLE CHAR (40), PUBLISHER_CODE CHAR, FOREIGN KEY (PUBLISHER_CODE) REFERENCES PUBLISHER (PUBLISHER_CODE), TYPE CHAR (3), PRICE DECIMAL (4), PAPERBACK CHAR (1));`



 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
```

Information that was added into the PUBLISHER table:

```
MySQL [rdatabase]> 

INSERT INTO PUBLISHER (PUBLISHER_CODE, PUBLISHER_NAME, CITY)
    -> VALUES ('WP', 'Westview Press', 'Boulder CO');

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MySQL [rdatabase]> `SELECT * FROM PUBLISHER;`

+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| PUBLISHER_CODE | PUBLISHER_NAME | CITY         |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| AH             | Arkham House   | Sauk City WI |
| WP             | Westview Press | Boulder CO   |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I am trying to insert information into `BOOK` table it gives me the following error:

```
MySQL [rdatabase]>

 INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_CODE, TITLE, PUBLISHER_CODE, TYPE, PRICE, PAPERBACK)
    -> VALUES ('0180', 'A Deepness in The Sky', 'TB', 'SFI', 7.19, 'Y');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rdatabase`.`BOOK`, CONSTRAINT `BOOK_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PUBLISHER_CODE`) REFERENCES `PUBLISHER` (`PUBLISHER_CODE`))
```

Comment: It seems that publisher `TB` does not exist, that is, the `PUBLISHER` table has no such record for `TB`.  Fix this, and the problem should go away.

Comment: Hi Tim! Thank you very much for your response! I have previously tried to replace 'TB' with value that matches one in PUBLISHER_CODE but I still got an error. Here is the code:                MySQL [rdatabase]> INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_CODE, TITLE, PUBLISHER_CODE, TYPE, PRICE, PAPERBACK)
    -> VALUES ('2281', 'Van Gogh and Gauguin', 'WP', 'ART', 21.00, 'No');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rzelench`.`BOOK`, CONSTRAINT `BOOK_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PUBLISHER_CODE`) REFERENCES `PUBLISHER` (`PUBLISHER_CODE`))  Any idea why thisdid not work?

Comment: Publisher `WP` is not the issue here, it's the absence of publisher `TB`.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Should I add TB into PUBLISHER table as one of the PUBLISHER_CODE values before I add TB into BOOK table?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  In fact, your foreign key constraints exist to make sure you get the current error you are seeing.

Comment: Instead of adding TB into PUBLISHER table I guess I can take available values from PUBLISHER table and insert them into to the BOOK table and technically it should work, correct? Then I don’t understand why WP did not work? It already exist in PUBLISHER_CODE. Sorry for being annoying, I just want to learn and avoid making this mistake in the future

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have mentioned `PUBLISHER_CODE` as foreign key in your `Book` table and there is no Publisher with `PUBLISHER_CODE` as `'TB'` in your `Publisher` table.  Foreign key constraint is failing there.

Comment: In other words if I try to add these VALUES ('0180', 'A Deepness in The Sky', 'AH', 'SFI', 7.19, 'Y') or VALUES ('0180', 'A Deepness in The Sky', 'WP', 'SFI', 7.19, 'Y') where I replaced TB with WP or AH which correspond to available values in PUBLISHER-CODE it should work?

Comment: I actually did it once with 'WP' and it still did not work.  And there was a 'WP' in PUBLISHER_CODE.   MySQL [rdatabase]> INSERT INTO BOOK (BOOK_CODE, TITLE, PUBLISHER_CODE, TYPE, PRICE, PAPERBACK)
    -> VALUES ('2281', 'Van Gogh and Gauguin', 'WP', 'ART', 21.00, 'No');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rdatabase`.`BOOK`, CONSTRAINT `BOOK_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PUBLISHER_CODE`) REFERENCES `PUBLISHER` (`PUBLISHER_CODE`))